# Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream. in Hystrix Dashboard issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator, hystrix, hystrix-dashboard

Before posting this question, I went through numerous links like : [Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream for Hystrix Dashboard with Spring Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792290/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-for-hystrix-dashboard-with-spring-clo) and [Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream in Spring Cloud + Hystrix + Turbine - MIME type ("text/plain") that is not "text/event-stream"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137023/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-spring-cloud-hystrix-turbine) and so on, but still things are not working for me.

**I am using Spring Boot V2.2.2.RELEASE.**

```
2020-01-14 22:52:23.805  INFO 8436 --- [io-8080-exec-10] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : 

Proxy opening connection to: http://localhost:8000/hystrix.stream


2020-01-14 22:52:23.806  INFO 8436 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : 

Proxy opening connection to: http://localhost:8000/hystrix.stream


2020-01-14 22:52:24.442  WARN 8436 --- [io-8080-exec-10] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Failed opening connection to http://localhost:8000/hystrix.stream : 404 : HTTP/1.1 404 
2020-01-14 22:52:24.442  WARN 8436 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Failed opening connection to http://localhost:8000/hystrix.stream : 404 : HTTP/1.1 404 
2020-01-14 22:52:37.391  INFO 8436 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : 

Proxy opening connection to: http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream


2020-01-14 22:52:37.397  INFO 8436 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : 

Proxy opening connection to: http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream


2020-01-14 22:52:37.488  WARN 8436 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Failed opening connection to http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream : 404 : HTTP/1.1 404 
2020-01-14 22:52:37.488  WARN 8436 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Failed opening connection to http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream : 404 : HTTP/1.1 404
```

[image]

**hystrix-dashboard::**

**HystrixDashboardApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHystrixDashboard
public class HystrixDashboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixDashboardApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-jdbcBatchUpdate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hystrix-dashboard</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

weather-app::

WeatherService.java

```
@Service
public class WeatherService {
    @Inject
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="unknown")
    public String getWeather() {
        return restTemplate.getForEntity("http://weather-service/weather", String.class).getBody();
    }

    public String unknown() {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~");
        return "unknown";
    }
}
```

WeatherAppApplication.java

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class WeatherAppApplication {
    @Inject
    private WeatherService weatherService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/current/weather")
    public String getWeather() {
        return "The current weather is " + weatherService.getWeather();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8000
spring.application.name=weather-app
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

**weather-service::**

**application.properties**

```
server.port=9000
spring.application.name=weather-service
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

WeatherServiceApplication.java

```
@RestController
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class WeatherServiceApplication {

    private String[] weather = new String[] {"sunny", "cloudy", "rainy", "windy"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/weather")
    public String getWeather() {
        int rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 4);
        return weather[rand];
    }
}
```

[image]

Source Code here: https://github.com/javaHelper/spring-cloud-cordinating-services/tree/master/Protecting-Systems-with-Circuit-Breakers

Comment: You source code link and the code in the question don't seem to match. Is the link correct?

Comment: Yes, its the same. The issue is coming when using SPring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE in all project and required dependencies

Comment: Still facing it? Or is it resolved. I can download your source code to see what's wrong if not.

Comment: Nope, it still not resolved. Request you to see why RabbitMQ shows events in different queue and other issues

Comment: Seems your dependencies are all over the place. There are a lot of collisions and duplicates in versions. Try clearing your cache and rebuild your project, fix the dependency issues first. Move common dependencies to a module that is being used by other modules.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I realized that, but after doing the same, messing with the other issues too. Could you please help me to refactor the code ?

Comment: @storesource - Could you please help me to make this working ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in **dashboard project** add this to your properties

```
hystrix:
  dashboard:
    proxy-stream-allow-list: "*"
```

and, in **weather-app** add this

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

then, open http://localhost:8080/hystrix and add http://localhost:8000/actuator/hystrix.stream

> https://github.com/adetiamarhadi/spring-cloud-hystrix-dashboard.git
> https://github.com/adetiamarhadi/spring-cloud-hystrix-weather-app.git

Comment: try with configs in [this](http://www.masterspringboot.com/cloud/netflix/configuring-hystrix-dashboard-in-your-spring-boot-application/) page if you couldn't get it working despite the above ones.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the below line in Hystrix Dashboard project it worked for me.

application.yml

```
hystrix:
  dashboard:
    proxy-stream-allow-list: "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

The Hystrix Dashboard stream URL that you have to provide is now:

http://localhost:8000/actuator/hystrix.stream

Answer (score 0):

Add below properties to `application.properties` file

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
hystrix.dashboard.proxy-stream-allow-list=*
```

Answer (score -1):

I just added below in `application.properties` file and it started working:

```
management.endpoint.hystrix.stream.enabled=true
```

Comment: with only this property value it wont be corrected.