# Hystrix not showing dashboard

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, hystrix-dashboard

**This is how my pom.xml looks like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>SalaryBox</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.salary.box</groupId>
    <artifactId>greeting-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**This is how my main class looks like**

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrixDashboard
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

**This is how my application properties looks like**

spring.application.name=greetings-service
service.message-service.id=messages-service
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

**This is how my controller looks like**

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

```
@Autowired
public GreetingsService greetingsService;

@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultMessage")
@RequestMapping("/greeting/{id}")
public Greeting findMyGreetingMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
    greeting.setMessage(greetingsService.getMessage(id));
    return greeting;
}

public Greeting defaultMessage(Long id){
    Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
    greeting.setMessage("Message service seems to be broken");
    return greeting;
}
```

}

**When I check the URL http://localhost:8082/actuator/hystrix.stream the stream seems to be generated as follows**

data: {"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"findMyGreetingMessage","group":"GreetingController","currentTime":1591920892870,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":0,"rollingCountBadRequests":0,"rollingCountCollapsedRequests":0,"rollingCountEmit":0,"rollingCountExceptionsThrown":0,"rollingCountFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackEmit":0,"rollingCountFallbackFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackMissing":0,"rollingCountFallbackRejection":0,"rollingCountFallbackSuccess":0,"rollingCountResponsesFromCache":0,"rollingCountSemaphoreRejected":0,"rollingCountShortCircuited":0,"rollingCountSuccess":0,"rollingCountThreadPoolRejected":0,"rollingCountTimeout":0,"currentConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"rollingMaxConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"latencyExecute_mean":0,"latencyExecute":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"latencyTotal_mean":0,"latencyTotal":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold":20,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds":5000,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage":50,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy":"THREAD","propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,"propertyValue_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride":null,"propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled":true,"propertyValue_requestLogEnabled":true,"reportingHosts":1,"threadPool":"GreetingController"}

data: {"type":"HystrixThreadPool","name":"GreetingController","currentTime":1591920892870,"currentActiveCount":0,"currentCompletedTaskCount":2,"currentCorePoolSize":10,"currentLargestPoolSize":2,"currentMaximumPoolSize":10,"currentPoolSize":2,"currentQueueSize":0,"currentTaskCount":2,"rollingCountThreadsExecuted":0,"rollingMaxActiveThreads":0,"rollingCountCommandRejections":0,"propertyValue_queueSizeRejectionThreshold":5,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"reportingHosts":1}

ping:

data: {"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"findMyGreetingMessage","group":"GreetingController","currentTime":1591920893373,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":0,"rollingCountBadRequests":0,"rollingCountCollapsedRequests":0,"rollingCountEmit":0,"rollingCountExceptionsThrown":0,"rollingCountFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackEmit":0,"rollingCountFallbackFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackMissing":0,"rollingCountFallbackRejection":0,"rollingCountFallbackSuccess":0,"rollingCountResponsesFromCache":0,"rollingCountSemaphoreRejected":0,"rollingCountShortCircuited":0,"rollingCountSuccess":0,"rollingCountThreadPoolRejected":0,"rollingCountTimeout":0,"currentConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"rollingMaxConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"latencyExecute_mean":0,"latencyExecute":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"latencyTotal_mean":0,"latencyTotal":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold":20,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds":5000,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage":50,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy":"THREAD","propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,"propertyValue_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride":null,"propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled":true,"propertyValue_requestLogEnabled":true,"reportingHosts":1,"threadPool":"GreetingController"}

data: {"type":"HystrixThreadPool","name":"GreetingController","currentTime":1591920893373,"currentActiveCount":0,"currentCompletedTaskCount":2,"currentCorePoolSize":10,"currentLargestPoolSize":2,"currentMaximumPoolSize":10,"currentPoolSize":2,"currentQueueSize":0,"currentTaskCount":2,"rollingCountThreadsExecuted":0,"rollingMaxActiveThreads":0,"rollingCountCommandRejections":0,"propertyValue_queueSizeRejectionThreshold":5,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"reportingHosts":1}

ping:

**But the dashboard seems to be stuck at this point even after refreshing it so many times and trying to hit the url so many times.**

[image]

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding proxyStreamAllowList, add this in application.properties -

```
hystrix.dashboard.proxyStreamAllowList = "*"
```

this thread looks similar - [Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream. in Hystrix Dashboard issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738969/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard-issue)